# Sci-Fi Channel film - Alien/parasite invasion where the parasites enter through the mouth

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-invasion

The movie has aliens/parasites outside surrounding a place, some of the smaller aliens take over people's body by entering through a human's mouth. the bigger aliens were outside. One scene has a lady seducing a guy and once she starts kissing him against a door with a window a alien goes out of her mouth into his splattering blood on the window of the door. Another scene has her talking to a guy with the inside of his stomach exposed with tons of alien parasites moving around in his stomach. Another scene I remember is a guy being trapped in a room trying to keep his mouth closed so a parasite can't take him over. The movie was in English, and I remember watching it on TV on the Sci-Fi channel before it was changed to SyFy, around 2006.

Comment: Could you add more details such as: when did you watch it and in which language? The more details you provide, the easier it is to help you.

Comment: I'd suspect Starship Troopers 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_2:_Hero_of_the_Federation . . . I hope someone can turn that into an answer if it looks correct to OP, as I don't have time to do the usually fantastic job that others do here . . .

Comment: Thank you so much Neil Slater and D rich, trying to remember that was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely [Starship Troopers II: Hero of the Federation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_2:_Hero_of_the_Federation)

> Eventually private Sahara and Dax, the male ex-hero of the federation,
>   find themselves facing a new breed of Arachnid—**a bug that infests the
>   human body by entering through the mouth and propagating inside the
>   brain.**

Answer (score 6):

Could you be thinking of *[Slither](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/Slither)* (warning, TV Tropes link)?

[image: *Slither* movie poster]

> Slither is a 2006 horror/comedy film written and directed by James Gunn. It is a Homage to gory B-Movie horror films. While not a massive commercial success, the film is something of a Cult Classic.
>
> The plot is essentially, an Alien Invasion film mixed with a Zombie Apocalypse. An alien parasite lands in rural America, infecting and taking control of local man Grant Grant (Michael Rooker). The alien impregnates a local woman, who gives birth (by having them eat her from the inside out) to thousands of "slugs", that share the original alien's mind. The slugs then enter a person's body through the mouth, killing them. The aliens then take control of the corpse. It's then up to the local police sheriff (Nathan Fillion), Grant's wife (Elizabeth Banks), the foul-mouthed Mayor, and a local teen to stop the alien before it can infect every living thing on the planet.

It's the right premise, and the right timeline, but I haven't found reference to a stomach exploding, and it came out in theatres in 2006, I think, not the Sci-Fi channel.

Answer (score 4):

I'd take a stab at either [Slither](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0439815/) or [Night of the Creeps](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091630/). Considering the time frame you're suggesting Night of the Creeps seem more likley though, I think I remember Slither having a theatrical run back in 2006 (but I might be mistaken on that). I recall seeing Night of the Creeps on SciFi-channel in Sweden back in the mid 90's so they definitely had the license to air it.

Answer (score 2):

May be Slugs.

There was a dog that was the main transmitter of the alien worms.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide any more details that suggest this might be the answer?

Comment: This could be Shivers from 1975. I remember there was a girl kissing and some parasite went from her throat into a man's throat. This was in an apartment block and the residents ended up trying to barricade against these creatures. But it was 41 years ago that I last watched it so I can't remember much more, sorry

Answer (score 0):

From some of what you've described, I'd say that *The Hidden* - from 1987 - is a really strong contender.

Comment: This answer has plenty of room for improvement.